# Connecting external displays over HDMI to 2016 MBP Touch Bar requires a restart

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, touch-bar

Any time I connect my two external displays (Samsung S27D850 over HDMI -> A-Data HDMI-USB-C adapters), I have to restart my MacBook Pro Touch Bar (15") in order for the screens to display the desktop.

Is there a workaround not having to do this, i.e., just plugging the displays in and voilà? It's frustrating coming back from a meeting to my workstation and having to restart.

Comment: See this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275978/119271.  Also,  I am not a fan of converting display signals which is what you are doing with that adapter.  That particular monitor has DP - I would use that interface rather than HDMI.

Comment: Also see this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/278720/119271 regarding signal types

Comment: So I should get a USB-C-Displayport adapter and use that cable in workstation use?

Another problem is that the meeting room displays are TV's with HDMI plugs, so I'm stuck with adapting HDMI there anyway. So the question holds - anyone know a workaround when I have a HDMI display?

Comment: I would use Display Port on your workstation and use an *active* [USB-C to HDMI](https://tr.im/TrendNet_USB_HDMI) adapter in the meeting room.

Comment: Thanks Allan, this was good to know. First of all, that underneath the USB-C there is a Displayport connection in the Macbook. So to avoid unnecessary conversions, I should use Displayport cables/adapters if possible. However, I found a workaround for my current setup with HDMI - see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for my setup with HDMI-USB-C-conversion: first plug the adapter to the computer, then the display cable to the adapter. Then the display works immediately.

If I plugged the monitor first into the adapter, it already "gives a signal" by showing a black screen instead of the "no signal" message. If I then connect the adapter to the computer with the monitor cable plugged into the adapter already, the display would detect, but the black screen would remain on the external display.

Not perfect for workstation use, but for meeting room situations, it's acceptable.