# How to connect MacBook Pro mid-2014 to monitor: hdmi, dp or usb-c?

Tags: display, usb, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I have a MacBook Pro mid-2014 with a HDMI port and a Thunderbolt 2 port (that I beleive doubles up as a miniDP port).

I have just bought an Acer H2777HU 27 inch (2560 x 1440 pixel) monitor. It has a HDMI port, DP port and USB-C port.

It only came with a DP cable, which does not fit the miniDP port on my MacBook.

So my question is: what is the best way to connect the two, ensuring that I get the full 2560 x 1440 resolution, 60Hz refresh and can use the built in speakers?

Is it:

HDMI to HDMI (are there different sizes of HDMI?)

miniDP to DP (does this cable exist?)

Thunderbolt 2 to USB-C (does this cable exist?)
 
Thank you

Comment: I’d go with the HDMI.

Comment: Is that because there is no conversion, simply HDMI to HDMI. Does HDMI support audio? Will HDMI support the resolution and 60Hz refresh? Are there different HDMI sizes I need to know about?

Comment: Are you using a Retina MacBook Pro? There's no miniDP port on the mid 2014 version. I'm typing this comment from one. HDMI is the way to go.

Comment: As mentioned in the opening post the Thunderbolt 2 port doubles as a miniDP port. I know because I've used it in the past as a miniDP port.

Answer (score 3):

According to this answer, you are probably better off with DisplayPort.

[Does USB-C to HDMI take more processing power than direct USB-C to DisplayPort?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278708/does-usb-c-to-hdmi-take-more-processing-power-than-direct-usb-c-to-displayport)

HDMI will work, but probably only give you a 30Hz refresh rate rather than 60Hz that your system is capable of.

Answer (score 1):

Use HDMI for the connection to your Acer monitor. The HDMI cable, whatever length you choose, should have the standard (Type A) connector at either end. This page at [eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/gds/Everything-You-Need-to-Know-About-HDMI-Cables-/10000000177630531/g.html) has everything you need to know about HDMI.