# Connect external display to Macbook Pro 2018: HDMI or DisplayPort?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt, hdmi

What is the best way to connect external display (3840 x 2160, 27") to MBPro 13" 2018? It only has 4 USB-C ports, so we have to use adapters.

Which is better, `USB-C - HDMI` or `USB-C - DisplayPort`? I reckon HDMI has troubles with FPS on Macbook Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/278720/279727) discussion, it's recommended to go with Display Port.

Quoting from the answer:

> **So, the question is actually: "Which would work better? Display Port to HDMI or Display Port to Display Port?"**
>
> Personally, I don't like converting signals from one to the next - I would go with a Display Port adapter and keep everything the same end-to-end. The less you have to convert, the less overhead and the less compatibility issues.

Credit to @Allan for the original answer.

Comment: Except DP may not be your best bet for image quality: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/2018-macbook-pro-blurry-displayport-output.2130629/#post-26512136